# (OAuthException) (#352) Video file format is not supported - (400) Bad Request on HttpHelper.OpenRead() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

While trying to upload a video using the Graph API and code from this post http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Uploading-Video-via-Graph-Api.aspx I'm getting the (OAuthException) (#352) Video file format is not supported result.

Tried with several files in different formats (mov, mp4, etc) and always the same result.

Below the exception details

{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()   at Facebook.HttpWebRequestWrapper.GetResponse() in C:\FacebookCSharpSDK-5.2.1.0-71da22b901a.src\FacebookCSharpSDK\Source\Facebook\FluentHttp\HttpHelper.cs:line 312   at FluentHttp.HttpHelper.OpenRead() in C:\FacebookCSharpSDK-5.2.1.0-71da22b901a.src\FacebookCSharpSDK\Source\Facebook\FluentHttp\HttpHelper.cs:line 661}

Did someone have a clue what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm running into a similar thing when trying to delete (deauthenticate) the user's permissions.  See http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8598614/facebook-c-sharp-api-return-400-when-deauthorizing-app

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? Have you reviewed the examples here: http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Uploading-Video-via-Graph-Api.aspx ? From experience with similar messages although not in the context of working with the Facebook API, I generally check that either the media's content-type is supported (for instance you could have a png file that has a content type along the lines of x-png) and, as Prabir demonstrates in the link I've provided, make sure you are also setting the content-type.